# Oracle client connectivity issue from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, database-administration, oracleclient

I have an user running a SSIS package which connects to Oracle server. When the user runs the package is failing with the error "Oracle Home not found". I'm Local admin on the server so when i execute the package it succeeds. I'm pretty sure the user need not to be a local admin as we have other servers where users are able to connect to oracle with out admin rights. Kindly let me know what permission levels i might need to check for the user in order to resolve the issue.

Note: The OS of the server is windows server 2012 and oracle provider installed is of version 12

Comment: Are you running this interactively in visual studio, from inside the catalog, using DTExec or from within a job?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The package is being executed from SSISDB catalog and user executing the package is a windows user